# Information about big data and hadoop

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I am a programmer and I am good in Database concept. I want to learn about big data and hadoop. But I don't have any past experience in these subjects. If anyone having good experience in big data and haddop please share how to start learning. If there are any institute or good websites please suggest. And if I need to do any course, please suggest that also. Thanks in advance.:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the tutorials from hortonworks a rather good starting point
http://hortonworks.com/tutorials/#tuts-developers

To deep dive a must read is Tom White's 'Hadoop: The Definitve Guide'.

'Hadoop in Practice' shows a lot of cookbook like examples.